# Strange result in C for loop

Tags: c, for-loop

I wrote the following code in C:

```
int main(){
  int i;
  double x;
  for (i = 0, x = -1; x<= 1; x = x + 0.025)
    printf("X = %.3f\n",x);
  return 0;
}
```

I don't know why, but the last line is "X = 0.975".

Can someone explain me why does the loop stop at this point and not precede one more step to X = 1?

Comment: Actually comparison of floating point number is made with some delta (we java prodrammers often do so), so try:

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  int i;
  double x;
  for (i = 0, x = -1; x - 1.00 <= 0.001; x = x + 0.025)
    printf("X = %.3f\n",x);
  return 0;
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to the wonderful world of floating point, where *nothing* is as it seems :-)

Most likely the final value of `x` is something like `1.0000000042` which, despite the fact it would be printed as `1.000`, is still *compared* as being greater than one.

If you modify your code thus, you'll see what I mean:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void) {
    int i;
    double x;
    for (i = 0, x = -1; x <= 1; x = x + 0.025)
        printf("X = %.3f (%.20f)\n", x, x);
    printf("X = %.3f (%.20f)\n", x, x);
    return 0;
}
```

The lines of that output are:

```
X = -1.000 (-1.00000000000000000000)
X = -0.975 (-0.97499999999999997780)
X = -0.950 (-0.94999999999999995559)
X = -0.925 (-0.92499999999999993339)
X = -0.900 (-0.89999999999999991118)
: : : : :
X = 0.900 (0.90000000000000113243)
X = 0.925 (0.92500000000000115463)
X = 0.950 (0.95000000000000117684)
X = 0.975 (0.97500000000000119904)
X = 1.000 (1.00000000000000111022)
```

and you can see the inaccuracies creeping in pretty quickly.

You may also want to print out the value `0.025` with that `%.20f` format specifier - you'll see something like:

```
0.02500000000000000139
```

because `25/1000` (or `1/40`) is one of those numbers which cannot be represented exactly in IEEE754 double precision.

Comment: I wonder why the compiler doesn't replace the condition `x<=1` with `x<=1.0000000042`.

Comment: @barak, because `1` _can_ be represented exactly. It's the cumulative errors of adding the inexact `0.025` that's causing the issue. Try it with steps that can be represented exactly (like `1/16` (0.0625)) and it works fine.